# Como fazer uma consulta através do LINQ ignorando acentos?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer uma *query* com LINQ que compare duas *strings* e ignore os acentos delas.

Isso sem que minha ***Collation*** no banco de dados esteja setada como ***AI (Accent Insensitive)*** e que eu não precise fazer um **`replace`** nas *strings* para sair removendo os acentos delas.

Por exemplo, ao tentar buscar um item pelo nome "Orquídea", ele deveria retornar tanto os itens que estão salvo no banco como "Orquídea", "Orquidea", "Orquidéa" e qualquer outro tipo de variação.

Já tentei utilizar o

```
string.Compare(string1, string2, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"), 
               CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) == 0
```

dentro da consulta LINQ, porém não funciona.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você só consegue isso se definir o `COLLATION` da coluna (ou da tabela, ou do banco) antes. Há algumas formas de se fazer isso.

Uma delas é [definindo um inicializador de base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401290/code-first-setting-database-collation), assim:

```
public class CollationInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MeuContexto>
{
    public override void InitializeDatabase(MeuContextocontext)
    {
        if(!context.Database.Exists())
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("DefaultConnection"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(string.Format("CREATE DATABASE {0} COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI", "MinhaBaseDeDados"), connection))
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
         }

         base.InitializeDatabase(context);
    }
}
```

E:

```
public class MeuContexto: DbContext
{
    public MeuContexto() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new CollationInitializer<MeuContexto>());
        if(!Database.Exists())
        {
            Database.Initialize(true);
         }
     } 
}
```

Outra é [definindo um interceptador de migrações](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054930/set-database-collation-in-entity-framework-code-first-initializer) para definir o `COLLATION` na hora em que o banco está sendo atualizado:

```
public class CreateDatabaseCollationInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    private readonly string _collation;

    public CreateDatabaseCollationInterceptor(string collation)
    {
        _collation = collation;
    }

    public void NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext) { }
    public void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        // Apenas para SQL Server
        if (Regex.IsMatch(command.CommandText, @"^create database \[.*]$"))
        {
            command.CommandText += " COLLATE " + _collation;
        }
    }

    public void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext) { }
    public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext) { }
    public void ScalarExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext) { }
    public void ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext) { }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No SQL Server é possível alterar a *collation* de uma coluna "*on the fly*" durante um `Select`.

Algo como:

```sql
Select *
From Entidades
Where (Coluna Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI) Like 'Tê%'
```

Esta *query* retorna todos as linhas onde a coluna `Nome` inicie com **"Te"**, independentemente se há ou não acentos ou diferenças de *casing*. Como por exemplo: "**Teste**", "**Téste**", "**téste**". Note também que o parâmetro usa acento, fiz isso pra ilustrar que ele também é desconsiderado.

Obviamente pra isso você vai precisar escrever a *query* para executá-la, mas creio que isso não seja problema.

Fiz um exemplo executando esta *query* com Entity Framework.

```cs
const string collation = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI";

using (var db = new Contexto())
{
    var resultado = db.Database.SqlQuery<Entidade>($"Select * From Entidades
                                                     Where (Nome Collate {collation}) 
                                                     Like '%{param}%'").ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

uma forma simples que encontrei foi assim. utilizo entity framework com mysql e utf8 -default collation,

```
using (controle_estoqueEntities entity = new controle_estoqueEntities())
        {
            return (from a in entity.clientes
                    where ( (a.nome_cliente == nome || a.nome_cliente.Contains(nome)))  
                    orderby a.nome_cliente
                    select new ClienteDTO
                    {IdCliente = a.idcliente,
                        NomeCliente = a.nome_cliente}).toList();
```

}