# Campo TextBox pesquisa Empresa e Categoria e Campo DropDownList Cidades pesquisa Cidades como fazer Includes no SQL - Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Desenvolvi um sistema Code First em `Asp.Net MVC` Neste desenvolvimento criei um relacionamento muito para muito e quero fazer uma pesquisa que inclua este relacionamentos em uma pesquisa, abaixo descrevo melhor em código o que desenvolvi

Alem da Empresa e Categoria que serão pesquisadas pelo `TextBox` quero também pesquisar junto com o `DropDownList` Cidades

Minha ideia da Síntese `(Empresa || Categoria) && Cidade`

Gostaria de também que na pesquisa do `TextBox` se o usuário digitar sem acento a pesquisa retorne o resultado, pois estou tendo problemas de retornos neste caso.

Um exemplo é tenho cadastrado **Farmácias** o usuário digita **Farma** ou **Farmacia** sem acento não retorna resultado.

Tenho as seguinte classes. Empresa, Categorias e a classe de relacionamento EmpresaCategorias.

Classe Empresa

```
public class Empresa
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public string Telefone { get; set; }

    public string Cidade {get; set;}

    public ICollection<EmpresaCategoria> CategoriaEmpresa { get; set; }
}
```

Classe Categoria

```
public class Categoria
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public ICollection<EmpresaCategoria> CategoriaEmpresa { get; set; }
}
```

Classe de Relacionamento NxN

```
public class EmpresaCategoria
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Categoria")]
    public int CategoriaId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Empresa")]
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }

    public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
    public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
}
```

No `Controller` tenho uma pesquisa que funciona, mas ela pesquisa somente Empresa, quero também incluir a Categoria

```
public ActionResult Resultado(string empresa, string cidade)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pesquisaEmpresaOuCategoria))
    {
        return Redirect("Index");
    }

    /*
     *ADICIONEI UM COMBO BOX COM A CIDADE
     *Quero Incluir a categoria nesta pesquisa
     *include
     */
    //AQUI PREENCHE O COMBO BOX COM CIDADES         
    ViewBag.cidade = new SelectList(db.Empresa.Select(a => a.Cidade).Distinct());

    return View(db.Empresa.Where(x => x.Nome.Contains(empresa) && x.Cidade.Contains(cidade)).ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a premissa da sua [dúvida anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/248926/20615), basta fazer o seguinte para a sua pesquisa:

```
public ActionResult Resultado(string pesquisaEmpresaOuCategoria, string cidade)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pesquisaEmpresaOuCategoria))
    {
        return Redirect("Index");
    }

    /*
     *Quero Incluir a categoria nesta pesquisa
     *include
     */

    return View(db.Empresa.Where(x => x.Cidade.Contains(cidade) && 
                                (x.Nome.Contains(pesquisaEmpresaOuCategoria) 
                                || x.CategoriaEmpresa.Any(c => c.Categoria.Nome.Contains(pesquisaEmpresaOuCategoria))))
                                .ToList());
}
```

Desta forma você está verificando se a empresa possui a cidade, juntamente com o nome ou categoria.

Sobre a questão da acentuação, [esta pergunta possui as respostas para o seu problema.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/204110/20615)

Comment: eu peguei este seu código e esta dando o seguinte erro, "bool" não contem uma definição para ToList()

Comment: @cyberlacs Eu coloquei os parênteses no local errado. Editei a resposta, teste agora

Comment: Perfeito funcionou mas ainda estava faltando um parênteses e assim resolvi o problema com sua solução.     return View(db.Empresa.Where(x => x.Cidade.Contains(cidade) &&
                                (x.Nome.Contains(empresa)
                                || x.CategoriaEmpresa.Any(c => c.Categoria.Nome.Contains(empresa))))
                                .ToList());

Comment: @cyberlacs Você está correto. É que você está retornando na `View(db.Empresa...)`. Em meus testes eu criei uma lista, e não tinha esse último parênteses. Valeu pelo comentário. P.S.: Editei a resposta conforme sua sugestão

Comment: estou com problemas nesta instrução referente ao retorno para o ToPagedList() fiz a pergunta nesta url você poderia ver qual o erro: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/522666?noredirect=1